# using InMemoryDatabase in multiple context

Tags: ef-core-3.1

I am using EF Core 3.1 and using in memory db for my xUnit tests. I am trying to use same in memory database into multiple context as below.

```
 DbContextOptionsBuilder _builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder();
 _builder.UseInMemoryDatabase("inMemoryDB");
 var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
 var parent = Parent(guid);
 var child1 = new Child(1, guid);
 var child2 = new Child(2, guid);

 using (var context = new AdministrationContext(_builder.Options))
 {
     parent.Child.Add(child1);
     parent.Child.Add(child2);
     context.Parents.Add(parent);
     context.SaveChanges();
 }

 using (var context = new AdministrationContext(_builder.Options))
 {
     // I can see saved parent object here as I am using AdministrationContext
     var list = context.Parents.ToList();
 }
 
 using (var context = new ReferenceContext(_builder.Options))
 {
     // getting empty list here as I am using ReferenceContext
     var list = context.Parents.ToList();
 }
```

I am having same parent and child object in reference context also.

From reference context, I am getting empty parent data.
This is working fine when I use sql server.

Does UseInMemoryDatabase should be used for one context type? Or am I missing anything here.

Comment: Did you read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/#approach-3-the-ef-core-in-memory-database)? "This database is in general **not suitable for testing applications that use EF Core**". That's probably why it has such restrictions.

Comment: Thanks @GertArnold. This means we should use in memory database to test EF Core. If we want to test the application, we have to use real database.

Comment: You're testing your application.